# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\multiusers\users\user_Validate.php on line 13

Tags: php

It seem like the error in the `if else` statement but I can't trace that error.

Can anyone please help me to solve this error.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("dbconfig.php");
    $table ="";
    $rurl="";
    extract($_REQUEST);
    if($role =="staff"){
        $table="multiusers_staff";
        $rurl="staff/trainer.php";
    }
    else($role=="student"){
        $table="multiusers_student";
        $rurl="student/suexecute.php";
    }
    $mail  = $role."_email";
    $uname = $role."_username";
    $pass  = $role."_password";
    echo $check1="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $mail ='$uemail' AND $pass ='$upwd' ";
    $login1 = $con->query($check1);
    $login_result1 = $login1->num_rows;
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($login1);
    if(is_array($row1)) {
        $_SESSION['s_usersid']      = $row1[0];
        $_SESSION['s_userrole']     = $role;
        $_SESSION['s_usersemail']   = $row1[$mail];
        $_SESSION['s_usersname']    = $row1[$uname];
    }
    else{ 
        echo $con->error;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION["s_usersemail"])) {
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('".$rurl."')</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: Are you missing a `;` ? or did you mean  `elseif` ?

Comment: You need to debug your code from top to bottom, you can put die before conditions and check up till which part your code is working or enclose all braces so that extra brace can come out.

Comment: dont use `extract($_REQUEST);` your asking for trouble, e.g: `?con=foobar`

Comment: or worse `?role=foobar&table=multiusers_staff WHERE id=1;--`

Answer (score 0):

```
else($role=="student") change this to else if ($role=="student")
```

else can not have a condition [Php Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `else`

`else` never have condition and you put condition here.

You have two ways

1. use `else` only.
2. use elseif($role=="student").

Code is as follows

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include("dbconfig.php");
    $table ="";
    $rurl="";
    extract($_REQUEST);
    if($role =="staff"){
        $table="multiusers_staff";
        $rurl="staff/trainer.php";
    }
    else{ //Or use elseif with condition `elseif($role=="student"){`
        $table="multiusers_student";
        $rurl="student/suexecute.php";
    }
    $mail  = $role."_email";
    $uname = $role."_username";
    $pass  = $role."_password";
    echo $check1="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $mail ='$uemail' AND $pass ='$upwd' ";
    $login1 = $con->query($check1);
    $login_result1 = $login1->num_rows;
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($login1);
    if(is_array($row1)) {
        $_SESSION['s_usersid']      = $row1[0];
        $_SESSION['s_userrole']     = $role;
        $_SESSION['s_usersemail']   = $row1[$mail];
        $_SESSION['s_usersname']    = $row1[$uname];
    }
    else{ 
        echo $con->error;
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION["s_usersemail"])) {
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('".$rurl."')</script>";
    }
?>
```